How to connect telegram chat bot with react website chat widget?
How to connect telegram chat bot with your website widget chat? So i can write message on my website and receive it in telegram. Should it be via socket.io and what are the best practices to do it? Don’t be mad by this question, just looking for practical advice, where to start from to implement this feature.
Googling it didn’t reveal real world examples or repositories to learn from. Only dry documentation.
